# Frank Sinatra in Science Fiction Films: What is significance?

Tags: blade-runner-2049, robocop

Frank was in Blade Runner 2049 and he also was singing in the 2014 remake of Robocop. Can anyone explain about the meaning of Frank Sinatra that has him shown in sort of similar films (both are about human vs artificial organism).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Frank Sinatra specifically cultivated a "timeless" character to his image.  He was quite choosy about what songs he would perform, and tried hard to avoid material that would become dated, instead performing a repertoire based on the [Great American Songbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_American_Songbook).  In public, he almost always dressed in very conventional suits or black tuxedos, nothing too flashy or too casual—again, nothing that would be likely to seem dated later on.  Apart from the eventual disappearance of his hat (as men largely stopped wearing hats with suits after the 1960s), his dress style did not change very much, over the entire second half of the twentieth century.

As a result, Sinatra, his image, and his music are iconic representations of twentieth-century America, without being too closely tied to any one particular period of time.  Juxtaposing Sinatra's classic look and classic sound with elements of a very different looking future are therefore an easy way to show that the setting of a film or television show is fundamentally different from the times that we are used to.

Comment: When I was a very young kid, I first heard It was a Very Good Year. It seems to me, it is a song about nostalgia and, of course, also aging and I wonder if that would have been a very good choice of a Sinatra song for certainly the first movie but also the second: both because it is relevant to the plight of the replicants in BR-- it is also about loss, and that sure seems relevant to BR 2049.

Answer (score 5):

Frank Sinatra is a hallmark figure of art (in this case the art of singing, underscored with a very typical visual style), a concept that artificial intelligence has trouble with to grasp and replicate.

Secondly, he gives off an incredible sense of 'zeitgeist'. Hearing Frank will put the atmosphere of the mid 20th century in anybody's mind. This gives a stark contrast between the olden days and the futuristic landscape the movie is trying to set up around the AI.

Reaching both of those goals - of benching AI against art and creating that atmosphere of changing times - can best be achieved with someone as well known as Frank Sinatra.